# "High" current MUXing of 4 HD LRA (AC voice coil) haptic motors

Tags: motor-controller, mosfet-driver, multiplexer, h-bridge, haptics

First off, thanks in advance for reading and for any ideas. Please forgive my ignorance on certain things; I'm a new industrial designer with some electronics experience, although I'm not an electrical engineer.

This project is for a special haptic glove for DIY medical vibrotactile-Coordinated Reset (vCR) nerve stimulation for a family member's Parkinsons.

I need to independently, although not necessarily concurrently, drive four 200mA AC (Voice coil) LRA (linear resonant actuator) haptic motors with sinusoidal waveforms from a compact wearable device, much like a large thick watch. Rough pcb size is slated to be 2" diameter (~50mm).

My first inclination was to use a dedicated haptic driver fed through a 2 x 1:4 MUX; however, a thorough bit of research led to the disappointing result that MUX ICs are VERY low current and would not support the current required to drive AC micro-motors.
If I had more space to work with, I would have constructed an array of FETs and enable-transistor array to form a custom multiplexor from discretes, but that's not easily possible with a preliminary block diagram of 16 FETs, and one each a quad NPN and PNP arrays.
In my extensive Google search, I came across a suggestion to use PWM drivers to drive a mono-directional motor array. However, I'm not aware of a way to achieve AC sine from a positive output PWM driving without some clever voltage clamping and timing, which I don't believe I have enough space for.

Driving it through the SoC is a possibility, however, I would prefer a standalone ASIC driver(s) so as to not suffer the timing variances from code execution and would still need the transistor arrays to drive the motors

4 driver chips may be the way I have to go but that's not tiny or elegant either.

I'm hoping I have missed something and someone can point me to a proper and reliable way to drive .25W transducers in a neat and compact way.

Thank you again for your time and any suggestions you may have!

-Mike

EDIT:
As these are essentially noiseless voice coil speakers, it may be useful to consider them as audio drivers that require an audio signal to drive them. In this case, a solution is required to MUX four speakers from a single low-voltage audio source with current sensing capability. Thank you!

Comment: Did you consider something like the L293 driver chip? It has 4 half H-drivers, or you could use it as 2 full H-drivers.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Unfortunately, general H-bridge are not suitable for generating a sinewave approximation as they output a square wave. I may be able to use high-frequency PWM with V/I sense and capacitive smoothing to achieve this, but this would not offload the sinewave iterative stepping from the SoC and may require a second MCU dedicated to motor control, which could be less than ideal for a low-power SoC. That is an option I may consider; using an SPI 8-channel motor controller and implementing some QAM simulated sine approximation. 
Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: How about using a tiny audio amp like PAM8304 per motor? You need a common sine wave signal for all and can multiplex them with the shutdown input.

Comment: My thoughts as a retired electronic engineer: A pcb size of 50 mm diameter is very ambitious, in my humble opinion it is impossible., a rectangle 50 mm by 150 mm may be doable. There is the DRV2605 Haptic Driver for ERM and LRA from Texas Instruments in a very small square package with only 1.47 mm width and length. Any multiplexer you build would be much larger than this. So I would use four DRV2605 and a microcontroller. But the DRV2605 is in a YZF BGA package with 9 solder balls. The BGA is very difficult to solder, a special oven and a lot of experience would be needed.

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.adafruit.com/ble-vibration-bracelet , the case is 65 by 71 mm